# Как воспользоваться OR в sequelize?

Tags: sqlite, sequelize.js

пишу CRM систему. Есть 2 таблицы: в одной пользователи (родители), в другой дети. У ребенка есть 2 графы для родителей (мама, папа).

Вопрос вот в чем, как мне получить нужного ребенка, если родитель может быть в одном из двух полей ребенка? До этого использовал findOne(), возможно ли здесь использовать or?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно, возможно. Смотрели опцию `where` и описание операторов в [документации](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html)?

```
const child = await Children.findOne({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [
     {
       Parent1: parentId
     },
     {
       Parent2: parentId
     }
    ]
  }
})
```